# How do I add a non-error message to my custom R function

Tags: r, function, error-handling

I have a custom function in r that involves writing and extracting terms from a model. For example:

```
myfunction <- function(data, outcome1, predictor1, predictor2){
  modelx <- glm(reformulate(predictor1, outcome1), data = data)
  modelx$aic
}

myfunction(data = mtcars, outcome1 = "mpg", predictor1 = "cyl")
```

In reality my function returns a dataframe, but I am making it simpler for the purposes of this question.

I would like to add a message to the function that automatically prints out the regression formula being called when I run my function. Outside of a function, I can print this information by running:

```
> reformulate("cyl", "mpg")
mpg ~ cyl
```

Therefore, I think I should be able to have my function print the message by adding something like this to the end of the function:

`simpleMessage(reformulate(predictor1, outcome1))`

However, I can't get this to work, and I understand that it has something to do with the fact that a function can only return one output value. How can I get this message to work?

Answer (score 0):

Close.  You can use `message()` directly, which actually does have a call to `simpleMessage()` within it, but chances are you don't have to actually worry about *constructing* a message.

You can pass the formula into `message()` (with the help of `format()` to print it out and still have your model output.

Below has this implemented as well as a quick demonstration for why `format()` is helpful with the `formula` class.

```r
myfunction <- function(data, outcome1, predictor1, predictor2){
  ref <- reformulate(predictor1, outcome1)  # save as object to use twice
  modelx <- glm(ref, data = data)
  message(format(ref))                      # message() with format()
  modelx$aic
}

myfunction(data = mtcars, outcome1 = "mpg", predictor1 = "cyl")
#> mpg ~ cyl
#> [1] 169.3064

# wrap with suppressMessages() to silence
suppressMessages(myfunction(data = mtcars, outcome1 = "mpg", predictor1 = "cyl"))
#> [1] 169.3064


# Why format?
ref <- reformulate("a", "b")
print(ref)
#> b ~ a
as.character(ref)
#> [1] "~" "b" "a"
format(ref)
#> [1] "b ~ a"
```

<sup>Created on 2022-10-06 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>